# SIGSEGV SEGV_MAPERR crash, only iOS 9.2.1

Tags: ios, objective-c, crash, segmentation-fault, crittercism

my app crash only iOS 9.2.1
The rest of devices okay. Crash in arbitrary places. Please help me =) I use crittercism. 
I am new to programming, tell me the right way please.
 Name SIGSEGV Reason SEGV_MAPERR

```
0   libobjc.A.dylib 0x0000000180d09bdc objc_msgSend + 24
1   UIKit 0x000000018696a654 -[UINibStringIDTable lookupKey:identifier:] + 128
2   UIKit 0x000000018696614c -[UINibDecoder containsValueForKey:] + 44
3   UIKit 0x0000000186698a8c -[UIScrollView initWithCoder:] + 1396
4   UIKit 0x0000000186b99b00 -[UICollectionView initWithCoder:] + 72
5   UIKit 0x000000018696667c UINibDecoderDecodeObjectForValue + 668
6   UIKit 0x00000001869663c4 -[UINibDecoder decodeObjectForKey:] + 332
7   UIKit 0x000000018684615c -[UIRuntimeConnection initWithCoder:] + 184
8   UIKit 0x000000018696667c UINibDecoderDecodeObjectForValue + 668
9   UIKit 0x00000001869667f4 UINibDecoderDecodeObjectForValue + 1044
10  UIKit 0x00000001869663c4 -[UINibDecoder decodeObjectForKey:] + 332
11  UIKit 0x0000000186845490 -[UINib instantiateWithOwner:options:] + 1216
12  UIKit 0x00000001866ef33c -[UIViewController _loadViewFromNibNamed:bundle:] + 372
13  UIKit 0x00000001864b8250 -[UIViewController loadView] + 172
14  UIKit 0x000000018637bd6c -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 140
15  UIKit 0x000000018643bda8 -[UINavigationController _layoutViewController:] + 68
16  UIKit 0x000000018643bc80 -[UINavigationController _updateScrollViewFromViewController:toViewController:] + 412
17  UIKit 0x000000018643aec8 -[UINavigationController _startTransition:fromViewController:toViewController:] + 140
18  UIKit 0x000000018643aa6c -[UINavigationController _startDeferredTransitionIfNeeded:] + 864
19  UIKit 0x000000018643a694 -[UINavigationController __viewWillLayoutSubviews] + 56
20  UIKit 0x000000018643a5fc -[UILayoutContainerView layoutSubviews] + 204
21  UIKit 0x0000000186377778 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 652
22  QuartzCore 0x0000000183d86b2c -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 144
23  QuartzCore 0x0000000183d81738 CA::Layer::layout_if_needed() + 288
24  QuartzCore 0x0000000183d815f8 CA::Layer::layout_and_display_if_needed() + 28
25  QuartzCore 0x0000000183d80c94 CA::Context::commit_transaction() + 248
26  QuartzCore 0x0000000183d809dc CA::Transaction::commit() + 508
27  QuartzCore 0x0000000183d7a0cc CA::Transaction::observer_callback() + 76
28  CoreFoundation 0x0000000181640588 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 28
29  CoreFoundation 0x000000018163e32c __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 368
30  CoreFoundation 0x000000018163e75c __CFRunLoopRun + 924
31  CoreFoundation 0x000000018156d680 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 380
32  GraphicsServices 0x0000000182a7c088 GSEventRunModal + 176
33  UIKit 0x00000001863e4d90 UIApplicationMain + 200
!   34  keep-app 0x0000000100060350 main (main.m:14)
35  libdyld.dylib 0x000000018110e8b8 start + 0
```

Name SIGSEGV Reason SEGV_MAPERR

```
0   libobjc.A.dylib 0x0000000180d09bdc objc_msgSend + 24
1   libcache.dylib 0x0000000181062b5c _entry_get_optionally_checking_collisions + 48
2   libcache.dylib 0x0000000181060dd0 _entry_table_resize + 304
3   libcache.dylib 0x0000000181061a9c cache_set_and_retain + 848
4   CoreFoundation 0x00000001815bb470 -[NSCache setObject:forKey:cost:] + 264
5   CoreUI 0x00000001861a2854 -[CUIStructuredThemeStore _canGetRenditionWithKey:isFPO:lookForSubstitutions:] + 856
6   CoreUI 0x00000001861c4d5c -[CUICatalog _resolvedRenditionKeyFromThemeRef:withBaseKey:scaleFactor:deviceIdiom:deviceSubtype:sizeClassHorizontal:sizeClassVertical:memoryClass:graphicsClass:graphicsFallBackOrder:] + 920
7   CoreUI 0x00000001861c40fc -[CUICatalog namedLookupWithName:scaleFactor:deviceIdiom:deviceSubtype:sizeClassHorizontal:sizeClassVertical:] + 144
8   UIKit 0x0000000186bd9994 __98-[_UIAssetManager imageNamed:scale:idiom:subtype:cachingOptions:sizeClassPair:attachCatalogImage:]_block_invoke + 420
9   UIKit 0x0000000186bd9734 -[_UIAssetManager imageNamed:scale:idiom:subtype:cachingOptions:sizeClassPair:attachCatalogImage:] + 208
10  UIKit 0x0000000186bd9f18 -[_UIAssetManager imageNamed:withTrait:] + 524
11  UIKit 0x0000000186773c5c _UIImageWithNameAndTraitCollection + 92
12  UIKit 0x0000000186396220 _UIImageWithName + 44
13  UIKit 0x00000001865d7650 -[UISlider createThumbViewNeue] + 160
14  UIKit 0x00000001865d6dec -[UISlider _initSubviews] + 68
15  UIKit 0x00000001865d69c8 -[UISlider layoutSubviews] + 136
16  UIKit 0x0000000186377778 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 652
17  QuartzCore 0x0000000183d86b2c -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 144
18  QuartzCore 0x0000000183d81738 CA::Layer::layout_if_needed() + 288
19  UIKit 0x000000018638e454 -[UIView(Hierarchy) layoutBelowIfNeeded] + 920
20  UIKit 0x000000018643c20c -[UINavigationController _layoutViewController:] + 1192
21  UIKit 0x0000000186439be4 -[UINavigationController _layoutTopViewController] + 224
22  UIKit 0x00000001864527dc -[UINavigationController navigationTransitionView:didEndTransition:fromView:toView:] + 724
23  UIKit 0x00000001864524c8 -[UINavigationTransitionView _notifyDelegateTransitionDidStopWithContext:] + 412
24  UIKit 0x00000001864521d0 -[UINavigationTransitionView _cleanupTransition] + 740
25  UIKit 0x00000001863b6e90 -[UIViewAnimationState sendDelegateAnimationDidStop:finished:] + 308
26  UIKit 0x00000001863b510c +[UIViewAnimationState popAnimationState] + 320
27  UIKit 0x0000000186445cec -[UINavigationTransitionView transition:fromView:toView:] + 1788
28  UIKit 0x000000018643b8c0 -[UINavigationController _startTransition:fromViewController:toViewController:] + 2692
29  UIKit 0x000000018643aa6c -[UINavigationController _startDeferredTransitionIfNeeded:] + 864
30  UIKit 0x000000018643a694 -[UINavigationController __viewWillLayoutSubviews] + 56
31  UIKit 0x000000018643a5fc -[UILayoutContainerView layoutSubviews] + 204
32  UIKit 0x0000000186377778 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 652
33  QuartzCore 0x0000000183d86b2c -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 144
34  QuartzCore 0x0000000183d81738 CA::Layer::layout_if_needed() + 288
35  QuartzCore 0x0000000183d815f8 CA::Layer::layout_and_display_if_needed() + 28
36  QuartzCore 0x0000000183d80c94 CA::Context::commit_transaction() + 248
37  QuartzCore 0x0000000183d809dc CA::Transaction::commit() + 508
38  QuartzCore 0x0000000183d7a0cc CA::Transaction::observer_callback() + 76
39  CoreFoundation 0x0000000181640588 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 28
40  CoreFoundation 0x000000018163e32c __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 368
41  CoreFoundation 0x000000018163e75c __CFRunLoopRun + 924
42  CoreFoundation 0x000000018156d680 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 380
43  GraphicsServices 0x0000000182a7c088 GSEventRunModal + 176
44  UIKit 0x00000001863e4d90 UIApplicationMain + 200
!   45  keep-app 0x00000001000b4350 main (main.m:14)
46  libdyld.dylib 0x000000018110e8b8 start + 0
```

Name SIGSEGV Reason SEGV_MAPERR

```
0   libsystem_malloc.dylib 0x0000000181257be8 szone_free + 2940
1   CoreFoundation 0x00000001815699a4 CFRelease + 1084
2   CoreUI 0x00000001861a240c -[CUIStructuredThemeStore renditionWithKey:usingKeySignature:] + 1596
3   CoreUI 0x00000001861c435c -[CUICatalog _storageRefForRendition:representsODRContent:] + 100
4   CoreUI 0x00000001861c4124 -[CUICatalog namedLookupWithName:scaleFactor:deviceIdiom:deviceSubtype:sizeClassHorizontal:sizeClassVertical:] + 184
5   UIKit 0x0000000186bd9994 __98-[_UIAssetManager imageNamed:scale:idiom:subtype:cachingOptions:sizeClassPair:attachCatalogImage:]_block_invoke + 420
6   UIKit 0x0000000186bd9734 -[_UIAssetManager imageNamed:scale:idiom:subtype:cachingOptions:sizeClassPair:attachCatalogImage:] + 208
7   UIKit 0x0000000186cec584 -[UIImageAsset imageWithTraitCollection:] + 400
8   UIKit 0x000000018672b058 -[UIImageView _resolveImageForTrait:] + 456
9   UIKit 0x000000018672a928 -[UIImageView _didMoveFromWindow:toWindow:] + 208
10  UIKit 0x0000000186376d7c -[UIView(Internal) _didMoveFromWindow:toWindow:] + 756
11  UIKit 0x0000000186376310 __45-[UIView(Hierarchy) _postMovedFromSuperview:]_block_invoke + 148
12  Foundation 0x0000000181fa9500 -[NSISEngine withBehaviors:performModifications:] + 164
13  UIKit 0x0000000186376194 -[UIView(Hierarchy) _postMovedFromSuperview:] + 528
14  UIKit 0x0000000186383b80 -[UIView(Internal) _addSubview:positioned:relativeTo:] + 1780
15  UIKit 0x0000000186575600 -[_UIParallaxDimmingView didMoveToWindow] + 176
16  UIKit 0x000000018637705c -[UIView(Internal) _didMoveFromWindow:toWindow:] + 1492
17  UIKit 0x0000000186376d7c -[UIView(Internal) _didMoveFromWindow:toWindow:] + 756
18  UIKit 0x0000000186376310 __45-[UIView(Hierarchy) _postMovedFromSuperview:]_block_invoke + 148
19  Foundation 0x0000000181fa9500 -[NSISEngine withBehaviors:performModifications:] + 164
20  UIKit 0x0000000186376194 -[UIView(Hierarchy) _postMovedFromSuperview:] + 528
21  UIKit 0x0000000186383b80 -[UIView(Internal) _addSubview:positioned:relativeTo:] + 1780
22  UIKit 0x0000000186615db4 __53-[_UINavigationParallaxTransition animateTransition:]_block_invoke_2 + 1652
23  UIKit 0x000000018638a964 +[UIView(Animation) performWithoutAnimation:] + 76
24  UIKit 0x0000000186575118 __53-[_UINavigationParallaxTransition animateTransition:]_block_invoke + 256
25  UIKit 0x0000000186690840 +[UIView(Internal) _performBlockDelayingTriggeringResponderEvents:] + 216
26  UIKit 0x0000000186574c90 -[_UINavigationParallaxTransition animateTransition:] + 1056
27  UIKit 0x000000018652e6a0 -[UINavigationController _startCustomTransition:] + 3540
28  UIKit 0x000000018643a9b8 -[UINavigationController _startDeferredTransitionIfNeeded:] + 684
29  UIKit 0x000000018643a694 -[UINavigationController __viewWillLayoutSubviews] + 56
30  UIKit 0x000000018643a5fc -[UILayoutContainerView layoutSubviews] + 204
31  UIKit 0x0000000186377778 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 652
32  QuartzCore 0x0000000183d86b2c -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 144
33  QuartzCore 0x0000000183d81738 CA::Layer::layout_if_needed() + 288
34  QuartzCore 0x0000000183d815f8 CA::Layer::layout_and_display_if_needed() + 28
35  QuartzCore 0x0000000183d80c94 CA::Context::commit_transaction() + 248
36  QuartzCore 0x0000000183d809dc CA::Transaction::commit() + 508
37  QuartzCore 0x0000000183d7a0cc CA::Transaction::observer_callback() + 76
38  CoreFoundation 0x0000000181640588 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 28
39  CoreFoundation 0x000000018163e32c __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 368
40  CoreFoundation 0x000000018163e75c __CFRunLoopRun + 924
41  CoreFoundation 0x000000018156d680 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 380
42  GraphicsServices 0x0000000182a7c088 GSEventRunModal + 176
43  UIKit 0x00000001863e4d90 UIApplicationMain + 200
!   44  keep-app 0x00000001000c0350 main (main.m:14)
45  libdyld.dylib 0x000000018110e8b8 start + 0
```

Unfortunately I do not have access to this device iOS 9.2.1. in the simulator and my device is working fine iOS 10.2

Comment: I put the check didReceiveMemoryWarning, thinking that's the problem. But it turned out that there is no =(

Comment: [Add an exception breakpoint](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17802662/exception-breakpoint-in-xcode) to make Xcode stop executing where the error happens. After knowing what crashes, try to fix it. If you can not make it, update your question to show the relevant code. Also please tag your question with the used language.

Comment: @shallowThought Thank you, I have a simulator 9.1, 9.2, 9.3, 10.2, runs great, also works on the real iPhone 6 10.2. Crash only at different places in one of the "application testers" from a different region, and he has set iOS 9.2 iPhone 6

Comment: @shamil what was the issue? I am in the same boat, can’t figure out what’s the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A SIGSEGV is an error / signal caused by an invalid memory reference or a segmentation fault. Seems like the app is trying to access an array element out of bounds or trying to use too much memory.

The way to fix this issue is to find out what the exception may be by making it happen on another device (or simulator), or getting the full console logs from that device. An easy way to do this might be to set exception breakpoints to see where the original exception that triggered the SIGSEGV is located.